# When validating a plugin type in Ave, what is the default?

Tags: plugins

I am currently using "Validate plugin" but getting bastardized results from the compiler? Does anyone know what the default plugin is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your system. If you are on Windows then it is "windows file system".